# find the limit of a probability connected to a Markov chain

Tags: probability

I'm stuck with the following problem:

A and B are playing a game. If A wins a round, the probability he will win the next one is 0.7. If A loses a round, the probability he will win the next one is 0.5. Also, A needs to pay B 5 dollars every time when he loses a round, and B needs to pay A 4 dollars if A wins a round. What is the probability that A will earn money after n rounds, when n goes to infinity? i.e. I need to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P($A has more money after $n$ rounds than before the game.$)$

If set A wins and B wins to be two states, I could have the transition matrix and then get the stationary probability for the two, but I don't know how to put the money part into this. The probability of winning depends on the result of last round while we need the total number of rounds that A wins. How to combine these two factors? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let $X_n $ represent the winner at round $n$, In the limit the probability of $X_n = A$ is $\frac{5}{8}$ -to see this solve the system $\begin{cases}0.7 p + 0.5 q &= p\\
\;\; \;\;p \; +\;\;\;q &= 1\end{cases}$

Let $W_n$ represent the wealth of player $A$

$$\Bbb{E}[W_{n+1} - W_n] = 4 \Bbb{P}(X_{n+1} = A \vert X_{n} = A)\Bbb{P}(X_n = A) - 5 \Bbb{P}(X_{n+1} = B \vert X_{n} = A)\Bbb{P}(X_n = A)  + 4 \Bbb{P}(X_{n+1} = A \vert X_{n} = B)\Bbb{P}(X_n = B) - 5 \Bbb{P}(X_{n+1} = B \vert X_{n} = B)\Bbb{P}(X_n = B) \\ \to  4 (0.7) \frac{5}{8} - 5 (0.3)\frac{5}{8}  + 4 (0.5) \frac{3}{8}  - 5 (0.5) \frac{3}{8} =\frac{5}{8} >0$$

therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} P$(A earns money from this game after n rounds) = 1

**remark:** Another way to see this is, after $n$ rounds, how many in average will $A$ win? $\frac{5}{8}$. Therefore his average net revenue will be 
 $$4 \frac{5}{8} - 5 \frac{3}{8} = \frac{5}{8}$$

Comment: The only problem in this derivation is that you haven't proven that the process converges to its invariant distribution. But this isn't so hard to prove.

Comment: Indeed that is an important step. This is true for any irreducible aperiodic finite state markov chain.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard result, but I think it warrants a comment, since your procedure is basically to find the invariant distribution initially, and then implicitly assume that it is the limiting distribution.

Comment: Excuse me, but the question means A has more money than before the game. It seems to me that you find the probability that A will win the nth round. Is that right?

Comment: @guest625 An outline of Conrado's procedure: first, he defined a process on the state space $\{ A,B \}$ where $X_n=A$ means "A wins the nth round" and $X_n=B$" means "B wins the nth round". Using your information he found that the transition matrix of this process, and calculated its invariant distribution. A standard theorem about Markov chains says that for a chain like yours, regardless of what the initial distribution is, the limiting distribution is the invariant distribution.

Comment: @guest625 Since this is the limiting distribution, eventually the behavior early on doesn't matter, and so A's winnings after N games will be approximately $5N/8 \cdot 4 - 3N/8 \cdot 5 = 5N/8$. This is closely related to a basic theorem from real analysis: if $x_n \to L$ then $y_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} \to L$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you so much for explaining this to me. I got it now.

Comment: Your final conclusion is not justified, since in general, $\mathbb{E}(W_n)\to\infty$ doesn't imply $\mathbb{P}(W_n>0)\to1$.

Comment: If it is true  that $\frac{ \#\{A \text {wins in $n$ rounds}\}}{n} \to \frac{5}{8}$  with probability  $1$ then why isn't the conclusion is justified?

Comment: The problem is the word "therefore" in the sentence:
$\mathbb{E}[W_{n+1}-W_n]\to 5/8$ therefore
 $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A \mbox{ earns money from this game after }n\mbox{ rounds })=1.$
Of course the result is true, and I know that *you* know that. But 
the structure of your solution could confuse weaker students.

Comment: what  I had in mind was something imprecise, that reflects the problems of the answer, I thought $W_n - W_{n-1}$ are asymptotically IID, so if in average he will win a positive amount of money, the law of large numbers should allow the conclusion that $P(\text{A ears after $n$ rounds}) \to 1$. But I can't really fix this part, so I will have to work on it. That might be a while

Comment: To prove that $W_n\to\infty$ almost surely is a more interesting problem, of course.